# How to make a horizontal recyclerview scroll to next item only

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

There is a horizontal recyclerview in my app and I want the sideways swipe to just bring next item to the centre. So when user swipes on the screen, the list should not scroll on for several items but just scroll to next item regardless of the swipe distance. Would it be possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: Have you tried using a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead? I think it'll fit your use case better

Comment: Upvoted @Dr.Nitpick :-) as that is a better option and lesser work.
Additionally, if you want to create such a recyclerView, you might want to extend it, control where the adapter inflates the view and restrict it to showing you only one item. I have never made one myself hence a comment